# Show "Save As" dialog instead of playing audio file with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

How I can force browser to show the "Save As" dialog instead of playing an audio file when a user clicks the anchor? I need that for a Chrome extension I am developing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supported in HTML5 by some browsers, you can use the `download` attribute of an `<a>`:

```
<a href="URL" download="new_filename.extension">Download</a>
```

Compatibility: http://caniuse.com/download

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/a#attr-download

Otherwise, you have to set it up on the server.

Comment: It is even better than I have been looking for because it allows me to specify file name. Than you.

Comment: @Glum No problem. Just make sure you read through both links I provided (and do more research on it). It's not implemented in many browsers/versions, and there's some quirks you should know

Comment: It does not matter because I am creating a Chrome Extension and Chrome support this feature since 14 version.

Answer (score 5):

The server delivering the audio file needs to provide the correct `Content-Disposition` HTTP header to trigger displaying the "Save As" dialog reliably on all browsers. If you were using PHP, you would do it like this:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
```

There's no way to do it with Javascript alone as this involves an interaction between the server and the browser.

Comment: Thanks but it is just a link to a thirdparty resource so I don't have an access to the server script.